# Преобразование сырой строки списка в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть строка `"[{1 : 1, 2 : 2},2,[3,4]]"` каким образом лучше всего преобразовать в питоновский список? Без использования eval.

Comment: если это JSON, то `json.loads()`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer только это не json, т.к. ключи не в кавычках

Answer (score 4):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list), если кратко, то так:

```
import ast
A = "[{1 : 1, 2 : 2},2,[3,4]]"
ast.literal_eval(A) [{1: 1, 2: 2}, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так:

```
А = "[{1 : 1, 2 : 2}, 2, [3,4]]"
for i in A:
    if i == "[" or "]" or "{" or "}" :
        A.remove(i)
    else:
        pass
```

Если remove не сработает попробуй pop