# Сделать из строки список кортежей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuple

Имеется строка

```
"[(1252,28),(1250,49),(1221,53),(1251,25),(1239,46)]"
```

Нужно сделать из нее список кортежей с цифрами.

Пока получилось сделать список из одного элемента со строкой

```
res = shift.strip('][').split(', ')
['(1252,28),(1250,49),(1221,53),(1251,25),(1239,46)']
```

Как теперь эту строку разбить на кортежи с цифрами??

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196519/Преобразование-сырой-строки-списка-в-список

Comment: Ошибку пишет malformed node or string: ['(1252,28),(1250,49),(1221,53),(1251,25),(1239,46)']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490955/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: Вот это ок! Благодарю